# How to express that a returned associated type implements a trait?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

This is abstract example that shows my problem, extracted from my attempts to refactor some Rust code and learn Rust simultaneously.

```
struct GenStruct<T> {
    field: T,
}

trait Marker {}
trait Return {}

impl Marker for i32 {}
impl Marker for u32 {}

// actually implement `Return` for GenStruct<M: Marker>,
// but compiler don't recognize that
impl Return for GenStruct<i32> {}
impl Return for GenStruct<u32> {}

struct Fake;

trait Trait<M: Marker> {
    type Ret: Return;
    fn meth(m: M) -> Self::Ret;
}

impl<M: Marker> Trait<M> for Fake {
    type Ret = GenStruct<M>;

    fn meth(m: M) -> GenStruct<M> {
        GenStruct { field: m }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `GenStruct<M>: Return` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:23:17
   |
23 | impl<M: Marker> Trait<M> for Fake {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Return` is not implemented for `GenStruct<M>`
   |
```

The compiler doesn't recognize that I actually implement `Return` for every `GenStruct<M>` where M is `Marker`. To fix it, I can write something like:

```
trait Marker {
    fn is_i32() -> bool;
}
trait Return {
    fn ret();
}

impl Marker for i32 {
    fn is_i32() -> bool {
        true
    }
}
impl Marker for u32 {
    fn is_i32() -> bool {
        false
    }
}

// compiler is satisfied by such implementation
impl<M: Marker> Return for GenStruct<M> {
    fn ret() {
        if M::is_i32() {
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

or use a trait object:

```
impl<M: Marker> Return for GenStruct<M> {}

trait Trait<'a, M: Marker + 'a> {
    fn meth(m: M) -> Box<Return + 'a>;
}

impl<'a, M: Marker + 'a> Trait<'a, M> for Fake {
    fn meth(m: M) -> Box<Return + 'a> {
        Box::new(GenStruct { field: m })
    }
}
```

However, if I use a trait object, I cannot write a specialized implementation of `Return` for `GenStruct<i32>` and `GenStruct<u32>`.

Will the compiler be able to recognize that I do implement `GenStruct<M: Marker>` or is my code is not idiomatic Rust? If my code is not idiomatic, then what is the right way to write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `where` clause, we can add an additional constraint on the generic `impl` so that it only applies if `GenStruct<M>` indeed implements `Return`.

```
impl<M: Marker> Trait<M> for Fake
where
    GenStruct<M>: Return,
{
    type Ret = GenStruct<M>;

    fn meth(m: M) -> GenStruct<M> {
        GenStruct { field: m }
    }
}
```

Rust 1.33 even indicates this via help text:

```
   = help: consider adding a `where GenStruct<M>: Return` bound
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> // actually implement `Return` for GenStruct<M: Marker>,
> // but compiler don't recognize that
> impl Return for GenStruct<i32> {}
> impl Return for GenStruct<u32> {}
> ```

Why do you think that you are implementing `Return` for any `GenStruct<M: Marker>`? This only implements it for two specific variants. The types that implement a trait are not a closed set; anyone can add new implementations of the trait in the future. The Rust designers don't want to allow the changes of a downstream crate to affect the compilation of your crate — that way lies madness!

> ```
> impl<M: Marker> Return for GenStruct<M> {
>     fn ret() {
>         if M::is_i32() { } else { }
>     }
> }
> ```

This is the correct way of saying "for every `M` that implements `Marker`,  `GenStruct<M>` implements `Return`. It doesn't matter how or where someone implements the traits, because there is guaranteed to be an implementation.

> I cannot write a specialized implementation

That's correct, *for now*. There's an ongoing RFC, [RFC 1020: impl specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) that aims to allow specialization in these cases.

Comment: Thank you for information. "anyone can add new implementations of the trait in the future" - that is what I didn't take into account